# System filter search by tag, is not working properly. (in some cases)

Tags: discussion, bug

sorry for my English

```
1(unanswered >> no answer) 

2(questions >> fetured)

tag example: [android].
```

After trying a few times I realized that does not work like a normal search, what happens is that if you are in 1() and apply the filters you sent to 2(), when what I wanted, it is that seep/filtered into 1().

It is that you can use this alternative, because it occurred to me to try it but not comfortable:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android

and makes the search for tags in 1(), because if you put in 1() [android] in the search engine sends you to:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android

when should (or so I think) stay /unanswered/.

No if this is a bug or desired behavior, although perhaps I doing something wrong.

sorry for my English

Comment: if not well understood my question and Spanish speaking you can look here and understand better. Sorry my bad English -> http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/366/sistema-de-busqueda-filtrar-por-tag-no-funciona-correctamente-en-algunos-ca